# Как добавить файл в 7-zip архив с сохранением структуры каталогов?

Tags: c#, 7z

Использую `SevenZipSharp`.

```
    SevenZipCompressor.SetLibraryPath("7z.dll");
    SevenZipCompressor szc = new SevenZipCompressor();
    szc.DirectoryStructure = true;
    szc.PreserveDirectoryRoot = true;
    szc.ZipEncryptionMethod = ZipEncryptionMethod.Aes256;
    szc.CompressionMode = CompressionMode.Create;
```

Если добавить несколько файлов сразу, то каталоги создаются нормально

```
    szc.CompressFilesEncrypted("test.7z", "123", @"C:\Test\Test2\123.txt", @"C:\Test\Test\123.txt", @"C:\Test\123.txt");
```

А если добавлять по одному, то все файлы записываются в корень архива.

```
    szc.CompressFilesEncrypted("test.7z", "123", @"C:\Test\Test2\123.txt");
    szc.CompressionMode = CompressionMode.Append;
    szc.CompressFilesEncrypted("test.7z", "123", @"C:\Test\Test\123.txt");
    szc.CompressFilesEncrypted("test.7z", "123", @"C:\Test\123.txt");
```

В итоге получается 3 файла *123.txt* в корне.

Что я делаю не так? Как добавлять по одному файлу с сохранением полного пути?

Comment: Хм. У `SevenZipSharp`, видимо, _вовсе_ нет документации? Я, по крайней мере, нагуглить на смог.

Comment: Попробуйте перегрузку с CommonRootLength, она должна по идее делать то, что нужно.

Comment: @VladD только сорсы, только хардкор!

Comment: @andreycha: Ага, я в них и смотрю. Код просто берёт список файлов, находит common root, и пакует начиная от него. Так что проблема ТС неудивительна.

Comment: @VladD а что за длину-то там нужно передавать?)

Comment: @a1bT: Судя по всему, к-во каталогов, которые надо отбросить, а остальные не отбрасывать.

Comment: @VladD а я понял, что длину общего пути, т.е. "C:\Test\", т.е. 8.

Comment: @andreycha: В символах или в каталогах? Ну, в крайнем случае подойдёт метод научного тыка.

Comment: @VladD в символах. `string res = ""; ... res += splittedFileNames[0][i] + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar; ... return res.Length;`

Comment: @andreycha: Хм, и правда.

Comment: @a1bT: Судя по всему, это в символах. Пробуйте!

Comment: @VladD так что видимо ТС надо вызывать отдельные методы, передавая в каждый 8.

Comment: @VladD добавьте ответ, пожалуйста. Не люблю вопросы без ответов, всплывающие наверх :).

Comment: @andreycha: Ответ наполовину ваш :)

Comment: @VladD сделайте общим :).

Comment: ну добавьте уже кто-нибудь. работает)

Comment: Окей, сейчас напишу.

Comment: если передать 0 то создает начиная с буквы диска, если 3 то с первого каталога. а если 1 то первое идет двоеточие, а дальше петрушка какая-то)

Comment: Ну, если путь начинается в двоеточия, библиотеке становиться не по себе :) Это баг, думаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно передавать длину общего пути для всех файлов:

```
string commonPath = "C:\\Test\\";
int commonPathLength = commonPath.Length;

szc.CompressFilesEncrypted("test.7z", commonPathLength, "123", @"C:\Test\Test2\123.txt");
szc.CompressionMode = CompressionMode.Append;
szc.CompressFilesEncrypted("test.7z", commonPathLength, "123", @"C:\Test\Test\123.txt");
szc.CompressFilesEncrypted("test.7z", commonPathLength, "123", @"C:\Test\123.txt");
```

---

Судя по [исходникам](https://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SevenZip/SevenZipCompressor.cs) (к сожалению, у проекта нету документации), метод `CompressFilesEncrypted` отличает часть пути, которая принадлежит архиву, от части пути *внутри* архива, при помощи вычисления общей части пути всех переданных файлов.

```
public void CompressFilesEncrypted(
    string archiveName, string password, params string[] fileFullNames)
{
    CompressFilesEncrypted(archiveName, CommonRoot(fileFullNames), password, fileFullNames);
}
```

То есть, если переданы файлы `C:\Test\Test2\123.txt` и `C:\Test\Test4\123.txt`, то общей частью будет `C:\Test\`. А вот для одного файла общей частью оказывается весь путь.

Поэтому и приходится вычислять нужную общую длину вручную, и передавать, используя перезагрузку с длиной.

Comment: Это не особо хороший вариант - каждый вызов `CompressFilesEncrypted()` влечет за собой открытие, перестроение, и закрытие файла архива. В лучшем случае, перестраивается только индекс, начало, и конец архива.  В худшем - каждый раз весь архив перестроится целиком, с переархивацией всех файлов. Если файлы более-менее крупные, то и нагрузка на систему будет очень не малая, даже не смотря на "SSD-шки и быстрые процессоры/память буквально в каждом домашнем ПК"

Comment: @SergeyRufanov а это вопрос к автору, зачем ему понадобилось добавлять файлы по одному.

Answer (score 3):

Для упаковки нескольких файлов предназначен метод `CompressFileDictionary` - он позволяет полностью контролировать структуру имен в архиве.

На вход ему первым аргументом подается `Dictionary<string, string>`, с будущим путем в архиве в качестве ключа и настоящим именем архивируемого файла в качестве значения.

Если хотите полные имена - просто добавьте полное имя файла одновременно и в ключ и в значение:

```
var archiveName = "C:\\foo\\bar.7z";

var sevenZip = new SevenZipCompressor();

var files = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var fileName in Directory.EnumerateFiles("\\\\some-pc\\SomeFiles\\"))
{
    files.Add(fileName, fileName);
}

foreach (var fileName in Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\Another\\Directory"))
{
    files.Add(fileName, fileName);
}

var fileName = "D:\\And\\Just\\one.file";
files.Add(fileName, fileName);

sevenZip.CompressFileDictionary(files, archiveName, "YourPassword");
```

Если необходимы полные имена unix-подобном стиле - просто отрезайте корневой элемент пути(букву диска либо косую черту в UNC-путях) из внутриархивного названия файла.

Comment: а можно как-то получить данные файла в архиве (размер, индекс и т.д.), зная путь и не перебирая все файлы?